# map deleter isn't working in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have written a custom deleter here to delete individual map elements . But it isn't working . I know I can resolve this issue using unique pointer . But I want to know how to do that in map .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class A 
{ 
    int i;
    public: 
    A() { }
    A(int pi = 0):i(pi)   {  cout<<"A()\n"; }
    void show() const { cout<<i<<endl; }
    ~A()   {  cout<<"~A()\n"; }
};
struct Deleter
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator () (T *ptr)
    {
         delete ptr;
    }
};
int main()
{
    map<char, A *> mymap;
    mymap['a'] =  new A(30);
    mymap['b'] =  new A(20);
    mymap['c'] =  new A(10);
    map<char, A *>::iterator it;
    for(it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end() ; it++)
        it->second->show();
    for_each(mymap.begin(),mymap.end(),Deleter());
    return 0;
}
```

It is showing compile time error .

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/algorithm:62:0,
                 from 4:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of '_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const char, A*> >; _Funct = Deleter]':
32:49:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:3755:14: error: no match for call to '(Deleter) (std::pair<const char, A*>&)'
  __f(*__first);
              ^
15:8: note: candidate is:
18:10: note: template<class T> void Deleter::operator()(T*)
18:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/algorithm:62:0,
                 from 4:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:3755:14: note:   mismatched types 'T*' and 'std::pair<const char, A*>'
  __f(*__first);
              ^
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message complained, you're trying to `delete` on `std::pair`, which is not a pointer at all. I guess you want to `delete` the 2nd member of `std::pair`, i.e. `A*`, you should change the `Deleter` to:

```
struct Deleter
{
    template <typename K, typename V>
    void operator () (std::pair<K, V>& p)
    {
         delete p.second;
    }
};
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/BBLJ38064)

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that `std::map::iterator::operator*` returns the
   value but it actually returns `std::pair<const char,A*>&`

Working code:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e18bd4600575d39a

Answer (score 0):

Map iterators iterate over pairs of key and value. You must rewrite your deleter to accept such a pair:

```
struct Deleter {
    template<typename K, typename T>
    void operator() (std::pair<typename K, typename T> &p) {
       delete p.second;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> template argument deduction/substitution failed:  [...]
>   note:   mismatched types 'T*' and 'std::pair'
>     __f(*__first);

It seems enough: you're expecting a *pointer* but `for_each` gives you a *value*, in simple terms.

```
__f(*__first);  // notice *
```

So make:

```
struct Deleter
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator () (T pair)
    {
         delete pair.second;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The deleter visits the pair, so you want:

```
struct Deleter
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator () (T p)
    {
         delete p.second;
    }
};
```